# How we can store values of variables across Bootstrapper and MSIs getting called from that Bootstrapper

Tags: wix

I have created a Wix Installer which has following structure

- It has Bootstrapper
- It has MSI1
- It has MSI2
- The task of Bootstrapper is to provide options to user as which
  application he wants to install. Based on his selection MSI1 or MSI2
  will be launched.

Now both MSIs need to collect information of Database.

My requirement is that if I collect DB information from MSI1, I want to pass that information to MSI2 from Bootstrapper(as after MSI1 user will choose MSI2 from Bootstrapper)

We don't want the end user to provide this database information again and again.

Please note that we cannot collect the database information from Bootstrapper itself, as the user may go to installer source and execute MSI1 or MSI2 directly.

Any one has idea how we can store values of variables across Bootstrapper and MSIs getting called from that Bootstrapper?

Answer (score 1):

Write that information to a well-known registry location during the installation.

[Here's](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/) a resource to the "remember me pattern" blog post that Rob has written. I know it's bad practice to just link a blog post that may not exist in the future but I also don't want to just copy most of it.

The basic idea is to save properties that may be defined by the user at run-time into the registry. When you run the installer again, you can try to read that registry location and load up the properties from a previous run of the installer so you already know what the user is going to write.

In this case, your 2nd installer will know about the well know registry location that the first installer will write the db information to. Now the 2nd installer can read this information when it is run afterwards and use it during hte installation which means the customer doesn't have to re-enter the same information for both installs.

You can combine this with custom actions to encode sensitive information and decode it at run time. This is also a very commonly used technique for remembering the install directory of a product as this is something that is commonly changed by the user at run-time.

---

I reread the question and realized that getting the information from the bootstrapper is not something you can do but I'll leave this part of my answer here anyways. *[I think you could gather the information in the bootstrapper and pass it to the MSIs. Just write that information during the install to a registry location and you can read it if it exists when installing if the user runs just from the MSI]*

---

Alternatively you can update your bootstrapper's UI to gather this information and pass it in to both installers. This requires a bit of research into how the bootstrapper application works and how it generates its UI and stores properties. And again, you should use the remember me technique to read the already entered properties from the registry if they exist so you can pre-populate fields with the previous values on subsequent runs of your installation.